# Differential equation $y'(t) = e^{-t \, y(t)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was confronted to this equation $y^{'}(t) = e^{-t \, y(t)}$; I don't feel it's possible to explicitly solve it, but I don't see how to explain that it's not possible...
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Very few nonlinear DEs have closed form solutions.  I think this is one of them.  But to *prove* that would be beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, let’s find a series representation using the Taylor series:

$$c=y(a),k=y’(a)$$

Our solution at $t=a$ is:

$$y’=e^{-ty}\implies y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{y^{(n)}(a)(t-a)^n}{n!}$$

Here are some nth derivative values:

$$y(a)=c\\y’(a)=e^{-ty(a)}=e^{-ct}\\y’’(a)=-e^{-ty(a)}(ty’(a)+y(a))=-e^{-ct}(tk+c)\\y^{(3)}(a)=e^{-tc}(t^2k^2-ty’’(a)+2tck-2k+c^2) =e^{-tc}(t^2k^2-te^{-ct}(tk+c)+2tck-2k+c^2) \\y^{(4)}(a)=e^{-ct}(-t y^{(3)}(a)-3y’’(a)-(kt+c)^3+3(kt+c)(ty’’(a)+2k))= e^{-ct}(-t e^{-tc}(t^2k^2-te^{-ct}(tk+c)+2tck-2k+c^2)+3 e^{-ct}(tk+c)-(kt+c)^3+3(kt+c)(-t e^{-ct}(tk+c) +2k)) $$

Therefore:

$$y(t)=c+ e^{-tc}(t-a)-\frac12 e^{-ct}(tk+c) (t-a)^2+\frac16 e^{-tc}(t^2k^2-te^{-ct}(tk+c)+2tck-2k+c^2)  (t-a)^3+\frac 1{24} e^{-ct}(-t e^{-tc}(t^2k^2-te^{-ct}(tk+c)+2tck-2k+c^2)+3 e^{-ct}(tk+c)-(kt+c)^3+3(kt+c)(-t e^{-ct}(tk+c) +2k))  (t-a)^4+…$$

Your $y(t)$ looks like the following using [this plotter](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/%7Enesterd/apps/slopefields.html):

[image]

Please correct me and give me feedback!